# About $f(s)=\sum_{a^2+b^2>0} \frac{(-1)^{a^2+b^2}}{(a^2+b^2)^s}=0$ and the Extended Riemann Hypothesis.

Tags: prime-numbers, intuition, normed-spaces, riemann-hypothesis

Let $s$ be a complex number with a strictly positive real part  ($Re(s)>0$).

Let $f(s)=\sum_{a^2+b^2>0} \dfrac{(-1)^{a^2+b^2}}{(a^2+b^2)^s}$

where the sum runs over all positive integers $a,b$ such that $a^2+b^2>0$ and *not* allowing multiplicity (as e.g. $x^2+y^2=q^2+s^2$ is counted only once).

(see David Speyers comment and below)

Notice $a^2+b^2$ is a norm.

Also notice this has a strongly related euler form : $f_2(s)=\prod_{p=a^2+b^2=1 mod 4} (1+1/p^s)$ for odd primes $p$.

($p=a^2+b^2=1 mod 4$ for odd primes $p$ follows from Fermat's Christmas theorem )

Is it true that :

1) $f(s)$ is meromorphic for $Re(s)>0$

2) $\dfrac{f'(s)}{f(s)}$ has a simple pole at $s=1$

3) $\dfrac{f'(s)}{f(s)}$ has no other poles than at $s=1$

4) If $Re(s)>0$ and $f(s)=0$ then $Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$ or at least that is believed by most mathematicians.

This is an analogue to the Riemann Hypothesis.

Is this a part of the Extended Riemann Hypothesis ?? Or did I misunderstood the Extended Riemann Hypothesis ?

Does all this lead to a kind of PNT for primes of the form 1 mod 4 ? An explicit formula for primes of the form $a^2 + b^2$ based on the zero's of $f(s)$ ?

Analogue questions for $G(s)=\sum_{a^3+b^3+c^3>0} \dfrac{(-1)^{a^3+b^3+c^3}}{(a^3+b^3+c^3)^s}$.

Notice $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is also a norm of a ring. (I think a UFD ring )

Update : Sorry $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is *not* the norm of a ring apparantly. However the question remains and I note that there about - I think - $O(\frac{x}{\ln^\frac{2}{3}(x)})$  integer numbers between $2$ and $x$ of the form $a^3+b^3+c^3$.

I also updated the OP based upon the helpfull comments of David Speyer. (and my reconsideration of "things")

Update 2 : It seems my estimate for the amount of numbers of the form $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is either wrong or unproven, see my link in my comment.

Comment: see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Riemann_hypothesis#Extended_Riemann_hypothesis_.28ERH.29

Comment: and also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Christmas_Theorem

Comment: The answer to this question will generally be that this function is pretty similar to the $\zeta$ function of the Gaussian integers and the Extended Riemann Hypothesis has something relevant to say about it. It's proving a nuisance to answer because of the following details in your phrasing, which make your question unclear:

Comment: It is not true that $\sum_{a^2+b^2>0} (-1)^{a^2+b^2}/(a^2+b^2)^s = \prod_{p \equiv 1 \bmod 4} (1+p^{-s})$. If you intend the sum to count each way of writing $n$ as $a^2+b^2$ separately, then the correct product is $4 (-1+2^{-s}+4^{-s}+8^{-s}+\cdots) \prod_{p \equiv 1 \bmod 4} (1-p^{-s})^{-2} \prod_{p \equiv 3 \bmod 4} (1-p^{-2s})^{-1}$. For example, the coefficient of $25^{-s}$ is $16$ because $25=a^2+b^2$ for $(a,b) = (\pm 3, \pm 4)$, $(\pm 4, \pm 3)$, $(\pm 0, \pm 5)$ and $(\pm 5, \pm 4)$.

Comment: Other interpretations are possible. I would suggest that it would be clarifying to say what you think the coefficients of $n^{-s}$ are (and why) for $n=1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $9$, $25$, $50$ and $65$.

Comment: Finally, there is no commutative ring for which $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is a norm. Were you intending the norm from the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-1)$? That's $a^3+c^3+c^3-3 a b c$. That ring isn't a domain, so people usually don't work with it, but we should be able to relate it the $\zeta$ function of its quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ if that's what you want.

Comment: The $16$ in the comment three above this one should be $-16$, due to the $(-1)^{a^2+b^2} = (-1)^{25} = -1$ factor.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Thanks for the comments. I edited the OP to adress the multiple ways to write as a sum of 2 squares and I mentioned that $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is not a norm of a ring.
I wonder what you find of the edit. Also I wonder if that sum of cubes still relates to the extended riemann hypothesis.
1 Question : You said $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is not the norm of a commutative ring. Is it the norm of a noncommutative ring ? Like a quaternion or such ?

Comment: Possibly related : http://oeis.org/A078129

Comment: Probably not related but intresting : http://oeis.org/A078132

Comment: Let a(n) be the sequence of sums of 3 positive cubes.
Davenport proved that a(n) << n^(54/47 + e) for every e > 0. [Charles R Greathouse IV, Mar 26, 2012] 
 
 REFERENCES  
H. Davenport, Sums of three positive cubes, J. London Math. Soc., 25 (1950), 339-343. Coll. Works III p. 999.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer How do you show that a polynomial is not a norm of any ring ? Maybe this should be posted as a seperate question. But maybe this has an easy answer or has already been asked.

Comment: A norm form always factors as a product of linear polynomials over the algebraic closure of the base field. The converse doesn't hold; that's the subject of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125222 , which I've been meaning to write a partial answer to for a while. But you just need the forward direction here: $x^3+y^3+z^3$ doesn't factor over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: My davenport reference is wrong. Credit to tommy1729 for pointing it out. Beware that mistake occurs often on the internet.